# Is "has the idea" used appropriately in this sentence?

Tags: vocabulary

> "Unto" usually **has** the idea of something being presented or given to someone/something.

When I read the sentence above I noticed that the writer, a native of English language, used **has** in a way that in Italian language wouldn't be accepted as correct, not even figuratively, just because words are not able to think.

So, the questions are: Does this way of using "has" sound natural or idiomatic in English language? Or, wouldn't it be better using "suggests" in the sentence above?

Comment: Carlo, you're generating questions from your own questions :)

Comment: English and Italian are different in how _have_ and _be_ are used. There are times where English would use _be_ ("I am your age"), and Italian would use _avere_ (_ho la tua stessa età_); there are times where English would use _have_, and Italian _essere_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Has* can have the meaning of *contains, as being a part of something*.

> The car has a door.  The table has 4 legs.

In the quoted usage it is not *Unto* that is having(thinking) an idea, but rather the idea of being presented something is a part of the essence of the word *unto*.  That is, *unto* has, *associated with it,* the idea of something being presented...

Answer (score 3):

*Has the idea* in this case uses the words literally, rather than idiomatically, so it has nothing to do with the idiom *have an idea*, which means *invent a concept* or *come up with a thought*.

- ***Have*** here is ‘possessive’ in the broadest sense, indicating not that the word ‘owns’ the idea, has some sort of legal title to it, but that  the sense is ‘proper’ or ‘appropriate’ to it , that the idea is a ‘property’ of the word.
- And ***idea*** here is also used in a very broad sense to mean not so much a narrow intellectual conception but a mental area or domain.

*Has the idea* is a fairly loose, colloquial way of expressing *bears the sense*.